# Is This a Bug in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using mysql and php (Laravel) and facing a very strange situation .

I am trying get an encrypted user type and user id and decrypt it . and then find the records for that user id .

my code is like this . i am using Laravel framework .

```
        $key = Config::get('app.key');
        $decodedUserIDwithType = base64_decode($encryptedUserIDwithType);
        $decryptedUserIDwithType = mcrypt_decrypt(XXXXX , $key, $decodedUserIDwithType, XXXXXX);
        $userIDwithType = $decryptedUserIDwithType;
```

I am expecting the decoded value to be something like this

```
id@100
```

so i will explode it by @ and find the user id , here it is 100 .

for testing i have changed the encrypted value by manually adding one or two characters . when i decrypt i got something like

```
id@100������������������������]u甀�+&�fj�W�ZЪS��d��]3�]"
```

and after i explode this i will get the id as `100���]u甀�+&�fj�W�ZЪS��d��]3�]"`

now i select all raws with same id using .

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id

**it will select the recordes with id = 100 even the actual id is** `100���]u甀�+&�fj�W�ZЪS��d��]3�]"`

so weird . the type of the id column is `INT` may be that is why it is matched .

but from my point of view it is very bad , because my whole logic got incorrect because of this .

I checked this query both in Laravel and raw MySQL Query , the results are the same .

Any Ideas , Thanks in advance .

**UPDATE**

> I understand the point mentioned by Shadow, but how to handle a
>   scenario like this , from decryption i expect id like 100 , but if i
>   got something like 1ASASAS, if you cast it to int it will be 1 (this
>   is just for example) . now the problem is my database has a user id 1
>   also , so now you can see how much trouble i am in because i will get an
>   incorrect user , sadly this is related to payment :P . some incorrect
>   users wallet will be topped up . ha ha .how to handle this

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: version: 5.5.42

Comment: I think it's just the encoding of your column

Comment: I think the garbage has already been inserted. It's not something buggy during select ;-)

Comment: Nope actually . the Encryption stuff we created yesterday so cannot be .:( all the ID's are just INT

Comment: About the type casting issues, it works as [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html). For instance, `SELECT CAST('123abc' AS UNSIGNED)` returns `123`.

Comment: I think @NewbeeDev is pointing on the right direction, that looks as an usual encoding problem. Looks like the data stored is not in a good state.

If you echo the `$encryptedUserIDwithType` does is look well formed?
Have you checked that the column in the DB match your encoding?
Have you double checked the encoding process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is a feature in MySQL described in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) section of the MySQL manual:

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

When MySQL converts a string to a number, it evaluates the characters starting from the left as long as the characters can be interpreted as part of a number and stops, if it encounters a character that cannot be considered as part of a number. In case of `100���]u甀�+&�fj�W�ZЪS��d��]`, the first `�` cannot be interpreted as a part of the number, so MySQL stops after `100`. The characters after 100 seem to be some kind of garbage anyway and you should check your php code why it produces that garbage.

Comment: *This is not a bug, this is a feature* - said every developer ever, hahahaha.

Comment: At least MySQL developers got it documented :)

Comment: @Shadow , I understand the point , but how to handle a scenario like this , from decryption i expect id like 100 , but i get something like 1ASASAS . if you cast it to int it will be 1 (this is just for example) . now the problem is my database has a user id 1 also , so now you can see how much f*****d i am because i will get an incorrect user , sadly this is related to payment :P . some incorrect users wallet will be topped up . ha ha .how to handle this

Comment: If you have a different question on top of the original one, pls ask it in its own topic. It is unfair to add a completely different question to the original one, even if the follow-up question is related to the original one.